# Change row expansion icon in table

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9

I am working on an angular app. In this I am using primeng table row expansion feature. Example with code is as follows:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v12/#/table/rowexpansion

In this primeng is using their own icon on row expansion, code for which is as follows:

```
<button type="button" pButton pRipple [pRowToggler]="product" class="p-button-text p-button-rounded p-button-plain" [icon]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'"></button>
```

Stackblitz :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablerowexpansion-demo

I don't want to use their icon. I want to use my own icon when row is expanded and when row is collapsed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using primefaces to show icons.
So just add your icons as some custom icons to the style.css and then replace them with the old ones.

1- Add custom icons to style.css:

```
.custom-svg-icon-1 {
   background: url('https://www.svgrepo.com/show/305186/close.svg');
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
 }
```

2- Use the custom icons in your button tag:

```
       <button
         type="button"
         pButton
         pRipple
         [pRowToggler]="product"
         class="p-button-text p-button-rounded p-button-plain"
         [icon]="expanded ? 'pi custom-svg-icon-1' : 'pi custom-svg-icon-0'"
       ></button>
```

The result:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablerowexpansion-demo-p4m51s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try this-
in your **html component file**, change the button's icon classes:

```
<button [icon]="expanded ? 'myArrowDown' : 'myArrowRight'"></button>
```

Then go to **styles.css** file and create the icons, something like this:

```
.myArrowRight {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-image: url('path to your custom icon');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.myArrowDown {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-image: url('path to your custom icon');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
```